# Galaxy S3 Mini - my provider only offers micro and nano SIM cards

Tags: sim-card, samsung-galaxy-s-3-mini

I've ordered a [Samsung Galaxy S3 Mini] (hasn't arrived yet) :

http://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_i8190_galaxy_s_iii_mini-5033.php

On the above link, it says that it uses "Mini-SIM".

I've tried double-checking that info on Samsung's site, but there it only sais "Sim Support":

http://www.samsung.com/uk/consumer/mobile-devices/smartphones/android/GT-I8190RWABTU-spec

My problem is, my provider only lets me switch my standard SIM to Micro-SIM or Nano-SIM.

Is there a way to make any of these work with the Galaxy S3 Mini? Anyone who already owns such a phone has had this issue? (and hopefully solved it)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Mini-SIM is the same thing as a standard SIM nowadays. The term was coined back in the day when SIM cards were the size of a credit card. Thus, the current-day regular SIM was known as Mini-SIM. Micro-SIM is the next step (used in newer smartphones, examples from [GSMArena](http://www.gsmarena.com/results.php3?sName=&idMaker=0&idAvailability=0&YearAnnounced=0&nPriceLow=0&nPriceHigh=0&idCurrency=0&idFormFactor=0&idSIMType=2&idDualSIM=0&idQwerty=0&HeightMax=0&WidthMax=0&ThicknessMax=0&WeightMax=0&idOS=8&idOSVersion=0&idOSWhen=0&nminCPUMHz=0&nCPUCores=0&nminRAMMB=0&nminInternalStorageMB=0&idExpansionCard=0&idDisplay=0&nminDisplayX=0&nminDisplayY=0&nmaxDisplayX=0&nmaxDisplayY=0&fminDisplaySize=0&fmaxDisplaySize=0&nPixelDensity=0&idDisplayTech=0&idTouchscreen=0&idAccelerometer=0&idGyro=0&idCompass=0&id35mm=0&idCamera=0&idCameraFlash=0&idVideoRecorder=0&idSecondaryCamera=0&idGPS=0&bWLAN=0&idNFC=0&bEDGE=0&bGPRS=0&idBluetooth=0&bIR=0&bEmail=0&bWAP=0&bJava=0&idRadio=0&bMMS=0&idRingtones=0&sColor=&nBatteryCapacity=0&StandBy=0&TalkTime=0&sFreeText=)) and then there is the Nano-SIM (used only in iPhone 5, iPad mini and Asus PadFone Infinity, as far as I know).

See [GSM SIM card evolution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aGSM_SIM_card_evolution.svg) for graphical representation.

Comment: Doh, I see what you mean: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subscriber_identity_module Thanks, that's great news for me!